# Can we send a custom dimension (user scope) with an ecommerce transaction?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, transactions

We are using analytics.js to track page hits and transactions. Currently, our tracking code looks like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
//add content grouping here if required
ga('send', 'pageview');

if(receiptPage){
  //we call server here ONLY on the receipt page.
  //the results are loaded into the addTransaction and addItem

  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    //we set the following fields here:
    //id, affiliation, revenue, shipping, tax, currency
  });

  //for each item in the order we run:
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    //we set the following fields here:
    //id, name, sku, category, price, quantity, currency
  });

  ga('ecommerce:send');
}
```

We would like to add 2 custom dimension fields to the user scope - userID and country. We have access to both of those parameters on the server and can easily include them inside the if(receiptPage) declaration. We want to know exactly where to add our custom dimension parameter and how to trigger its collection.

According to [google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828) :

> Unlike other types of data, custom dimensions and metrics are sent to
>   Analytics as parameters attached to other hits, like pageviews,
>   events, or ecommerce transactions.

However, they only show examples of sending pageviews and events. We were unable to find any example displaying collection of a custom dimension parameter via a transaction hit.

The question is:
Can ga('ecommerce:send'); collect custom dimensions?
In that case we can do:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('send', 'pageview');
if(receiptPage){
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {/*somecode*/});
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {/*somecode*/});

  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'user555');
  ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Germany');

  ga('ecommerce:send');
}
```

Or, if ecommerce can't collect custom dimension data, we will have to move the sending of the pageview under the if statement. Could it cause problems if we call it after the ecommerce collection? :

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
if(receiptPage){
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {/*somecode*/});
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {/*somecode*/});

  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'user555');
  ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Germany');

  ga('ecommerce:send');
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Which solution should we choose and why? It is a sensitive place to experiment, so we would rather be certain rather than solving it by trial and error.

Comment: re: experiments, nothing stops you to create an extra property and send some dummy calls there without affecting your live account. Takes a few hours for the data to show up, but this is usually the most reliable way to tell if certain code works for your use case.

Comment: And adding to @EikePierstorff's comment, you can even create a dummy html page with the code in question and check the GA with that without impacting your live site at all. Having a staging site is imperative with web development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both solutions. They will trigger two requests to Google Analytics servers and transmit all the data you defined in your code.

First solution:
The second request has the "transaction" type defined and will include all the values defined in the lines before the "ga('ecommerce:send');".

Second solution:
The pageview request could be sufficient to send all the data and you don't need the ga('ecommerce:send') at all, but I'm not 100% sure.